# Make specific div or any element display on top of all others

Tags: html, css, z-index

I have the following tooltip:

```css
#left_div {
  max-height:170px;
  overflow-x:hidden;
  overflow-y:scroll;
}
a.tditems_tooltip {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  text-decoration:none;
}
a.tditems_tooltip span {
  position: absolute;
  max-width:400px;
  color:#FFFFFF;
  line-height:16px;
  padding:0;
  background:url('/layouts/background.gif');
  border: 1px solid #CFB57C;
  text-align: center;
  display: none;
  text-decoration:none;
  font-size: 12px;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 4px #AAAAAA;
}
a.tditems_tooltip span:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  left: 0%;
  margin-left: 150px;
  max-width:800px;
  text-decoration:none;
}
a:hover.tditems_tooltip span {
  display: inline-block;
  bottom: 100%;
  left: 0%;
  margin-left: -3px;
  z-index: 1000;
  text-decoration:none;
}
```

```html
<table border="0" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="1" width="400" height="300">
  <tr>
    <td width="50%">
      <div id="left_div">
        </br>
        </br>
        </br>
        </br>
        <a class="tditems_tooltip">
          <font color="red">TRIGGER</font>
          <span>
            <table border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="1" width="300">
              <tr bgcolor="green">
                  <td>CONTENT OF TOOLTIP</td>
              </tr>
            </table>
          </span>
        </a>
        </br>
        </br>
        </br>
        </br>
        </br>
        </br>
        </br>
        </br>
      </div>
    </td>
    <td width="50%">INSIGNIFICANT CONTENT</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

And so far It is working almost perfectly to what I intend to... Except for one thing: The tooltip (`span`) doesn't show on the top of all other elements of the page, instead shows behind it. Checkout the snippet above.

**UPDATE:**

> When I remove from the **CSS** the `overflow-x` and `overflow-y` from the `td` it shows the way intended, but I still need to specify a `max-height` to that `td`...

Any ideas?

Comment: `z-index` only applies to positioned elements. Also don't use the `<font>` tag.

Comment: @j08691 yea I only used it to make it clear what I was talking about, because the text **TRIGGER** color is red in the picture, about the `z-index`, the element of the tooltip is positioned, you can see it in the **CSS** lines at the top, why isn't it working then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First I wanted to thank all who came here and tried to help me! So I found the solution and I'm posting the whole snippet below.

Note that the changes were only in the **CSS**:

```
a.tditems_tooltip span > table {
  position: fixed;
  transform: translateY(-100%);
}
```

```css
#left_div {
  max-height:170px;
  overflow-x:hidden;
  overflow-y:scroll;
}
a.tditems_tooltip {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  text-decoration:none;
}
a.tditems_tooltip span {
  position: absolute;
  max-width:400px;
  color:#FFFFFF;
  line-height:16px;
  padding:0;
  background:url('/layouts/background.gif');
  border: 1px solid #CFB57C;
  text-align: center;
  display: none;
  text-decoration:none;
  font-size: 12px;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 4px #AAAAAA;
}
a.tditems_tooltip span:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  left: 0%;
  margin-left: 150px;
  max-width:800px;
  text-decoration:none;
}
a:hover.tditems_tooltip span {
  display: inline-block;
  bottom: 100%;
  left: 0%;
  margin-left: -3px;
  z-index: 1000;
  text-decoration:none;
}
a.tditems_tooltip span > table {
  position: fixed;
  transform: translateY(-100%);
}
```

```html
<table border="0" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="1" width="400" height="300">
  <tr>
    <td width="50%">
      <div id="left_div">
        </br>
        </br>
        </br>
        </br>
        <a class="tditems_tooltip">
          <font color="red">TRIGGER</font>
          <span>
            <table border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="1" width="300">
              <tr bgcolor="green">
                  <td>CONTENT OF TOOLTIP</td>
              </tr>
            </table>
          </span>
        </a>
        </br>
        </br>
        </br>
        </br>
        </br>
        </br>
        </br>
        </br>
      </div>
    </td>
    <td width="50%">INSIGNIFICANT CONTENT</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Hey! I'm glad you found your answer. JUST FYI, you shouldn't use `table`s for layout. Here's an article to help you understand why not: https://www.hotdesign.com/seybold/everything.html  Also there's tons of great online course material to help you learn to use `div`s and other dom elements as containers (like [free] https://www.codecademy.com/learn/make-a-website and [trial/pay] https://www.codeschool.com/courses/front-end-foundations )

Comment: Yo thanks! I found the content really interesting and I will look at it all, learning is never too much after all!

Comment: Tables have a lot of built-in properties and restrictions that make them really inconvenient to use for layout - especially compared to things like `<div>`s, `<article>`s, and other accessible, modern DOM elements. IMHO, the most important thing to learn is the difference between the css values for `display`. (ex `{display:block;}` vs `{display:inline-block;}` vs `{display:inline;}`). If you can learn those, laying out content becomes a LOT easier.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest to take it off the element `<table>` and instead put a `<div>` that wrap everything `<div style="display:table">` more over if you want it to be at the top of the table `margin:8px` is like you wrote:

```
margin-top:8px
margin-bottom:8px
margin-left:8px
margin-right:8px
```

So I guess it's better you'll put `margin-top:0;`
Another option to put an element at the top is

```
position:relative;
top:100%
```